# What is the significance of the title "Usagi drop"?

Tags: usagi-drop

I was wondering what was the meaning of the tile Usagi drop: literally it means "Bunny drop", but how is it related to the story? Is there some reference to somethings or is there some pun involved?

Comment: I think it's a slightly changed phrase meaning a child that has been abandoned by its parents, with the "child" replaced with "bunny". Coz she's cute.

Comment: @Hakase As far as I'm aware, there isn't any Japanese phrase/idiom that uses the word "drop" (in the context of abandonment or otherwise).

Comment: [According to some guy on Chiebukuro in 2011](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1471602274), the author has never commented on the origin of the name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[As senshin has mentioned in his comment](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1471602274), the author has never commented on the origin of the name. Thus, there are only fans' interpretation...

According to Japanese fans (on Japanese Yahoo! Answers: [1](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1471602274), [2](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1472097984)), the one that seems to make sense is:

> Usagi Drop → Usagi's drop → rabbit's (falling) teardrop

The first link explains more in detail that in the last volume of the manga,

> Daikichi confessed to Rin why he took her over.
>
>  Rin: Daikichi... you haven't met me before, but why you...
>  Daikichi: Your face... your crying face when you parted with grandpa... somehow...
>
>  The next panel shows Rin's crying face. Thus, *Usagi = Rin*.
>  The conclusion is, the title is about **Daikichi's determination to take Rin over when he saw her crying face**.

Also, the anime's OP show a teardrop just before the title appears.

The second link explains it in short, that the title is a wordplay.

> "Usagi" means *lonely*, and "Drop" means *teardrop*.
>  Combining the words, the title means **Rin, a lonely crybaby**.
>  ---
>  Further reading: in Japan, there's a popular term "lonely rabbit" because it's believed that "a rabbit can die if it's left alone". Extending that, there's also "rabbit-type girl" which is described as "a girl who often feels lonely".

Answer (score 0):

I believe this question is similar to

1. 'Where is the sniper?' in this 2008 video '[CIA Entrance Exam](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6HL-jUsIiN8&lc=UgzWh9DFWaUvgHv0j9l4AaABAg)'

The answer is

> 'You are the sniper.' You're seeing the POV of the sniper, but you're led to believe that from your POV, you'll see the sniper somewhere else.

2. ['Where/What/Who are the rabbits in Deceit?'](https://www.reddit.com/r/PlayDeceit/comments/rmpt40/is_asking_wherewhatwho_are_the_rabbits_in_deceit/) for the game [Deceit](https://deceit.fandom.com/wiki/Deceit_Wiki). Deceit features a lot of rabbits (oh rabbit / bunny like bunny drop) in the logo or posters or whatever, but you don't really see rabbits running around. So where are the rabbits in the deceit?

> The rabbits are the innocent who run away from the infected who are like lions or whatever.

3. Consider [this image](https://www.reddit.com/r/NinoNakano/comments/uwe2qa/theres_a_missing_card_for_the_royal_flush_wheres/) of [Nino Nakano](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/67368/what-is-this-metal-object-that-nino-is-rubbing-against-her-face-in-gotoubun-no-h) from [The Quintessential Quintuplets](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/49006/why-do-anime-mothers-often-get-the-short-end-of-the-stick/67494#67494)

> [image]

We see 4 out of 5 cards needed for a royal straight flush. Where is the Ace of Diamonds?

> It's not the diamonds on Nino's socks. Nino *is* the [ace of diamonds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ace_of_Diamond).

## Finally

So here, I haven't seen Bunny Drop / Usagi Drop, but after reading the plot preview, I immediately thought that the 'Bunny' is

> Rin, which is the same as Aki Tanaka♦'s answer.

## What is this trope?

I think it's like [Maybe The Real Treasure Was the Friends We Made Along the Way](https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/maybe-the-real-treasure-was-the-friends-we-made-along-the-way) or [the real treasure is the friends we made along the way](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/the_real_treasure_is_the_friends_we_made_along_the_way). On tv tropes:

1. [Worthless Treasure Twist](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/WorthlessTreasureTwist)
2. [It's the Journey That Counts](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ItsTheJourneyThatCounts)