# What is this metal object that Nino is rubbing against her face in Gotoubun no Hanayome?

Tags: culture, the-quintessential-quintuplets

See the picture for what I'm referring to. At the end of S02E03 of Gotoubun no Hanayome (aka Quintessential Quintuplets), Nino is lounging around in her residence, rubbing these metal-looking balls against her face.

What is this? My guess is it's some female-skin-care product, but I have no actual idea @.@.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is usually called *Small Face Roller*(小顔ローラー) or *Beautiful Face Roller*([美顔ローラー](https://www.amazon.co.jp/s?k=%E7%BE%8E%E9%A1%94%E3%83%AD%E3%83%BC%E3%83%A9%E3%83%BC&ref=pd_sl_62blw487x7_e), link to amazon.jp).

Personally I feel it is rather dubious whether it has any effect at all, but according to [here](https://toplog.jp/355270) for example, it is supposed to *prevent hanging skin, improve blood circulation, or soothe swollen face (by fatigue)*. Either way you are right in that it is a "beauty apparatus" mostly for women.

Sorry if the wording is not clear, I have little idea on the right term for the symptoms.

Comment: Perfect answer. Thank you! But I suppose I may as well ask: is this mostly a japanese thing? Or is it also a thing in western cultures? @.@

Comment: @chausies Apparently similar things are sold also [in the US](https://www.amazon.com/Massager-Electric-Anti-Aging-Wrinkles-Tightening/dp/B07Q5PD2YL/ref=sr_1_15?keywords=Skin+Roller&qid=1666486481&qu=eyJxc2MiOiI0LjkyIiwicXNhIjoiNC45NSIsInFzcCI6IjQuNzcifQ%3D%3D&sr=8-15). Have no idea how common it is, though. In Japan, it is widely known at least.

Comment: Is there any paper that support its effect? I think, by rubbing your skin more often, it can get your skin more loosened, i.e., get you more hanging skin.

Answer (score 0):

face sculptor or face massager

https://www.amazon.com/face-sculptor/s?k=face+sculptor

[image]

https://wwd.com/shop/shop-beauty/face-massagers-1235068497/

[image]

[First Impression of Skin Gym Face Sculptor | How to facial Massage | Bianca Janel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ToyzZ2TdLPw)

[S02E03 - What do you call the face rolling thing that Nino is holding please?](https://www.reddit.com/r/NinoNakano/comments/w7wwtc/s02e03_what_do_you_call_the_face_rolling_thing/)